# How to create API methods using rails & swagger docs for nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, resources, swagger

I have a rails application, using active record serializers to respond_to json or html. I'm using this to create a public API. I'm using devise simple http for basic authentication.

I'm using Swagger docs, via the following gems.

`gem 'swagger-docs' #for creating the swagger json format
gem 'swagger-ui_rails' #for generating the swanky active docs UI`

I have been able to create the json successfully for my main top level resources, via the controllers. For example, in "products_controller.rb":

```
swagger_controller :products, "Product Management"

  swagger_api :index do
    summary "Fetches all Products"
    param :query, :page, :integer, :optional, "Page number"
    response :unauthorized
    response :success
  end
```

The problem is how to setup for nested resources.

So, in my architecture, Products has_many Slots / Slots belong to Product. So, in my "slots_controller.rb", I have it setup in the same fashion:

```
swagger_controller :slots, "Slot Management"

  swagger_api :index do
    summary "Fetches all Slots for a Product"
    param :query, :page, :integer, :optional, "Page number"
    param :form, :product_id, :integer, :required, "Product id"
    response :unauthorized
    response :success
  end
```

I think it was wishful thinking, that providing the param of `:product_id` along with the controller action working with the product id to find slots for the given product, then swagger may auto-magically interpret this as a nested resource. It seems not, and instead, my slots API method in Swagger is looking for:

```
/api/v1/slots.json
```

instead of

```
/api/v1/products/#{product.id}/slots
```

How do I setup my swagger_controller to generate the correct nested url structure for Slots?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you've already solved this one, but you can use the `:path` param_type like so:

```
swagger_api :index do
  summary "Fetches all Slots for a Product"
  param :path, :product_id, :integer, :required, "Product id"
  param :query, :page, :integer, :optional, "Page number"
  response :unauthorized
  response :success
end
```

Comment: Thanks Marc. Actually, I ended up ditching swagger for the time being and instead am using [Slate](https://github.com/tripit/slate) to document my API. I may revert back to swagger to provide the active docs, but iterating with Slate is way quicker for the time being.